# Access nested iFrame in a div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to access an `iframe` with no `id` or `class` attribute inside a `div`.

This is currently what the source looks like.

```
<div id="cont">
    <iframe src="#" style="border: none; width: 500px; height: 196px; overflow: hidden" 
frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

I would like to change the `width` and `height` of the `iframe` and I think I need to do something like this, `setAttribute("height", "2000");`. I just don't know how to find that `iframe` because it doesn't have an `id` or `class` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you know the iframe's parent's ID, it should be trivial to select:

```
$('#cont > iframe')
```

Then you can set its height:

```
$('#cont > iframe').height(2000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, knew it had to be something simple. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
var $iframe = $("#cont iframe");
```

Then do whatever you want with it ^_^.

---

Or you can even do:

```
var $iframe = $("iframe", "#cont");
```

---

All in all you can do this at the end:

```
$iframe.height(2000);
```